# Getting urllib.error.URLError on python 3.8

Tags: python, pandas

After moving from python 3.7 to python 3.8 I started receiving this errors when I'm doing `pd.read_csv('https_link_here.csv')`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Dev Tools/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/Dev Tools/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/dmitry/projects/work/python_scripts/covid_cases_deaths_dashboard/covid_dashboard_v.2.2.py", line 202, in <module>
    inp_who = pd.read_csv('https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 434, in _read
    fp_or_buf, _, compression, should_close = get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 183, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    req = urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 137, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1393, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1353, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)>
```

When I'm changing interpreter back to python 3.7 everything going well.
How it could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing the same issue please go to python 3.8 folder and run `Install Certificates.command`